# how to do a distinct with select all

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct

I am trying to select all fields and get a distinct in 1 field where a certain condition is true but I am getting an error saying incorrect syntax this is what I have

```
var sql = @"SELECT * distinct threadID from Threadposts where profileID = 1";
```

I am new to mssql but can not figure out what is wrong with the query above, I simply want all fields included where profileID= 1 and select distinct values from threadID

Comment: Try `SELECT distinct *`

Comment: If you only want distinct values from threadID what should be shown for the other columns when duplicate rows have been excluded?

Comment: So what would you expect to get when one value for threadID has multiple values for some other column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be clearer about what you want. You are querying a tabled called `Threadposts` for records where the `profileID` is 1. This will return multiple rows with different values I expect.

Are you wanting to count how many posts were made by that person? Are you wanting a list of threads by that person?

```
-- count of rows
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Threadposts
WHERE profileID = 1

-- list of threads
SELECT *
FROM Threadposts
WHERE profileID = 1
```

If you are wanting something different then you'll need to update your question.

PS: the `DISTINCT` keyword will look at the data returned and give distinct values only, e.g. if you wanted distinct topics posted by this user regardless of if they created multiple threads with the same name:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ThreadTopic
FROM Threadposts
WHERE profileID = 1
```

Using `DISTINCT *` almost never makes sense, since each row will have a unique ID (hopefully) so will already be distinct.

Answer (score 1):

DISTINCT is essentially short-hand for GROUP BY on all selected columns when you don't need any aggregates. What you are asking for is a query where you are grouping on a single column, but not aggregating the remaining columns. That doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

In a table, a column may contain many duplicate values; and sometimes you only want to list the different (distinct) values. The DISTINCT keyword can be used to return only distinct (different) values.

You want to select all the columns but distinct only with a particular one (threadID)

Try using:

`var sql = @"SELECT DISTINCT ON threadID * FROM Threadposts WHERE profileID = 1;`